# Selecting a Value By Regex in a Dropdown Button with Selenium

Tags: python, regex, selenium

I'm having some problems in selecting values that are in a species of Dropdown Button. I've never seen a button that works in that way, it is equal to a dropdown menu, but it is classified in the website HTML as a button. So, selenium returns me an error when try to manipulate the button as if it were a menu.

Can you please help me to know what code should I run to select a value from the first dropdown menu of this  [Brazilian Central Bank website](https://www.bcb.gov.br/conversao)? The default value is `REAL (BRL)` and I want to use regular expressions to select the others.

edit:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame();

selector = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("button-converter-de")) 
options = selector.options
for index in range(0, len(options)-1):
    df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(eval(options[index])), ignore_index= True)

selector.select_by_index(df.loc[df.iloc[:,0].str.contains(str(moeda_origem))])
```

The error is:
"UnexpectedTagNameException: Select only works on select elements, not on button"

Comment: Please post the code that's giving you the error

Comment: @Energya OK, I'll edit the post with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page does not use default Select. Its dropdown is custom and, in order to work with it, do not use Selenium select and options, they won't work.

Try this instead:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get('https://www.bcb.gov.br/conversao')

# Click to open the dropdown
driver.find_element_by_id("button-converter-de").click()
sleep(2) # Make sure dropdown opened

# Search for dropdown options by their selector
options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#moedaBRL > li > a.dropdown-item')
print([o.text for o in options]) # this just prints all options, you can use your loop
```

I hope this helps, good luck!